# Questions about Ubuntu Wiki and LoCos

Tags: discussion, community

I want to ask some questions about Ubuntu Wiki and LoCo pages in it, are they relevant to AU? I'm hoping they'd fall under [community](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/community).

Comment: I think you'd have more luck on ubuntuforums.org, as the locos tend to get forums there (in some cases)

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix, well, the LoCo in question is just a recent startup and doesn't have anything like a *proper* forum yet. And my question is not about the LoCo, but about styles and conventions for LoCo's Ubuntu Wiki pages.

Comment: Just lurk other loco's pages, they already conform to the style, conventions, and standards afaik.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions regarding the wiki and LoCo (as a general, LoCo specific questions would probably be better served elsewhere) are on topic of Ask Ubuntu

Comment: Is the [tag:community] tag be appropriate for Ubuntu Wiki and the like?

Comment: @Oxwivi Yes, community tagged for locos would be great!, there's also a locoteams tag

Answer (score 1):

LoCo teams have their own tags and yes they would also fall under the "community" tag as LoCo teams are a major part of the Ubuntu Community world wide.